# Getting an Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Javascript, so this might be blindingly obvious, but the fiddle linked below fails with the following error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

http://jsfiddle.net/5SujV/

The code in question is

```
var previousNum = 0;
var currentNum = 0;
var sum = 0;
var fibNums = [1, 1];

while (currentNum < 4000000) {
    previousNum = fibNums[fibNums.Length - 2];
    currentNum = previousNum + fibNums[fibNums.Length - 1];
    fibNums.append(currentNum);
};

for (var x = 0; x < fibNums.Length; x++) {
    currentNum = fibNums[x];
    if (currentNum % 2 === 0) {
        sum += currentNum;
    };
};
console.log(sum.toString);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want `.push()` not `.append()` - also it's `.length` not `.Length`

Comment: Probably want `sum.toString()` too, but `console.log` usually takes care of conversion as necessary. Lots of little errors here. You need to pay very close attention to case and using the correct method names. Keep the [Mozilla MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) at the top of your bookmarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays do not have a function called `.append`. What you are looking for is [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
Also, I think you have a typo; did you mean `fibNums.length?`, `.Length` is not a valid property of arrays.

Also `console.log(sum.toString)` will not do what you expect. That will print out the function itself (or at-least a prettified version of it). You want to do `console.log(sum.toString())` to actually invoke the function. But even this is not necessary. JavaScript will implicitly convert the number type into a string, so `console.log(sum)` should be enough.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, still in Object Pascal mode where it's append. That, fixing the case on length (I hate case sensitivity) and tadman's suggestion to use toString() fixed it. Thanks!